# Ventilation in Attic Dormer

Tags: roof, attic, ventilation

The ventilation in my attic never seemed like it worked correctly. Here's the backstory:

There is a section of my teardown/rebuild home that protrudes about 3 1/2 feet from the rest of the house. The roof of this section is basically a dormer  at the end of the house that was constructed as an "overframe" so that the dormer framing sits on top of the framing and playwood of the rest of the roof.

There is no access to the attic in the dormer from the main attic.

There are no soffit vents in this section of the roof (even though the ridge vent extends across the entire roof).

How much of a factor to the overall ventilation of the attic is this section with basically no intake? Would cutting through the dormer plywood to open up the closed in section help? If not, what would other options for improving ventilation here be (e.g. a low intake gable vent on that back corner).

Adding some pictures for reference.

[image]
[image]

Inside back corner of attic with not soffit vents:

[image]

Comment: No pictures yet.  are there soffits?  Can vents be added to them or change to ventilated soffits?  Simple/non living attic spaces you want low intakes, but they should almost equal to outlet(width of roof opening by length, 1 inch wide by 5 feet works out to 60 sq inches)

Comment: With pictures, they look like vented soffits, unknown if there is blockages/solid wood under(above) them.

Comment: Yes, the dormer section does have soffit vents perpendicular to the ones one the main roof. However, the plywood between the main attic and dormer prevents airflow between the 2 (see 3rd picture). I also have no way to confirm if the dormer section has an actual ridge vent.